# Are We a Prompt-Providing Service?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

[This question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/revisions/2100/1) by a new user asks us "what to write?"  The question could, I think be perfectly fine as a suggestion for how to get ideas.  That may even be what the OP intended.

As a "suggest something to me, please" I think it is off-topic.  To me that reads like asking for a recipe on SeasonedAdvice - it's polling the community and will generate more noise than signals.

I should note that I think the answers are awesome and written as if to an on-topic question.

The question is, do you agree?  Do you think we should allow questions like this?  Should we not?  Why or why not?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were asking "do we answer questions quickly enough?" and I'm thinking, what is this, Domino's? We answer your question in 30 minutes or it's free? ;)

Comment: @Lauren: I took the question the same way, and... was a bit disappointed ;-) The question is missing a "Writing", methinks.

Comment: @Lauren, @jae - and now? :)

Comment: Yes, that's better. Although I have to admit the original was funnier. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with your assessment. "Give me a writing prompt," just doesn't seem like a question we can support. It is too broad and vague.

Asking for a prompt with a specific set of criteria would be *better*, as answers could at least be judged based on how well they fit the criteria. Ultimately though, I think a more appropriate question would ask where to find writing prompts, as this is more likely to generate useful resources for the original poster and for others. I am an ardent believer in the "teach a man to fish" philosophy.

Interestingly, the answers that have been posted to that question are mostly addressing "how to fight writer's block". This, I think, is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of the answers, which I've found to be generally high quality.

Comment: perhaps close these as duplicates of a canonical "dealing with writer's block" question?

Comment: @Jeff - sounds like a plan.  I think we are in the process of writing the answers to the canonical question.

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, no, I don't think these questions are on-topic. I'd hate to see Writers.SE turn into a site to come to to get writing prompts when you're stuck. I'm also firmly in the category that you can't rely on others to tell you what to write; part of being a writer is coming up with those ideas on your own.